# How To Add [hide] and [show] Option Beside Table Of Contents Title?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, tableofcontents

I've used the following code to make a **Table of Contents** in my WP blog post.

Added this **CSS Code** to custom CSS file:

```
 #toc_container {
    background: #f9f9f9 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    display: table;
    font-size: 95%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding: 20px;
    width: auto;}

.toc_title {
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;}

#toc_container li, #toc_container ul, #toc_container ul li{
    list-style: outside none none !important;}
```

and the **HTML Code** that I've used for it is:

```
<div id="toc_container">
<p class="toc_title">Contents</p>
<ul class="toc_list">
  <li><a href="#First_Point_Header">1 First Point Header</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_1">1.1 First Sub Point 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_2">1.2 First Sub Point 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#Second_Point_Header">2 Second Point Header</a></li>
<li><a href="#Third_Point_Header">3 Third Point Header</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Now, how can I add a [hide] and [show] option beside the **Contents** (title) just like they do in Wikipedia Table of Contents? Replies appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried already? Please edit your question to share it so we can know why it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not too tricky :)

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    ...HEAD Stuff...
    <script>
    var hideTOC = function(){
        var hideThese = document.getElementsByClassName("toc_list");
        for (var i = 0; i < hideThese.length; i++){
            hideThese[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        document.getElementById("showTOC").style.display = "";
    }
    var showTOC = function(){
        var showThese = document.getElementsByClassName("toc_list");
        for (var i = 0; i < showThese.length; i++){
            showThese[i].style.display = "";
        }
        document.getElementById("showTOC").style.display = "none";
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    ...BODY Stuff...
    <div id="toc_container">
        <p class="toc_title">Contents [<a href='javascript:void(null)' class='toc_list' onclick='hideTOC()'>hide</a><a href='javascript:void(null)' id='showTOC' style="display:none;" onclick='showTOC()'>show</a>]</p>
        <ul class="toc_list">
            <li><a href="#First_Point_Header">1 First Point Header</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_1">1.1 First Sub Point 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_2">1.2 First Sub Point 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#Second_Point_Header">2 Second Point Header</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Third_Point_Header">3 Third Point Header</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    ...BODY Stuff...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems not working for my Wordpress Blog :(

Tried it.. added the Javascript through Head, Footer and Post Injections plugin and then as per your instruction CSS code on Additional CSS section and HTML in the post on the Table of Contents...

Comment: can you please recheck that code that you've given and suggest me if anything else needed to be added?

Comment: tocHidable the class seems doesn't exists.

Comment: You're right. I used the wrong class name. I've made the corrections. Give that another try.

Comment: Tried it.. but still not working in my Wordpress blog :(

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much. Just a tiny matter.. while I'm clicking on Hide option there's showing some extra space. Can you please suggest how to remove that space? You can see the picture here: https://ibb.co/czxPrp

Comment: It could easily depend on what you have after that block. What does your code look like now?